# trouble with running e2e on bitbucket pipeline

Tags: angular, docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

i trying to configure CI process for my app developed with angular-cli.

Currently i managed to make pipeline run the karma tests and my problems is with e2e ("ng e2e" command of angular-cli)

here is my bitbucket
_pipelines.yml:

```
image: node:7.6.0

pipelines:
 default:
   - step:
    script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - npm install
      - ng test --singleRun=true
      - ng e2e --env=prod
```

and here is output of pipeline:

```
[11:59:09] I/file_manager - creating folder /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[11:59:10] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.29.zip
[11:59:10] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.29
[11:59:10] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:59:10] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[11:59:10] E/launcher - Server terminated early with status 127
[11:59:10] E/launcher - Error: Server terminated early with status 127
    at earlyTermination.catch.e (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:777:24)
    at Function.createSession (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:709:29)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts:90:25)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:225:39)
    at q.then.then (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.ts:391:27)
    at _fulfilled (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at ./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    [11:59:10] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are launching chrome via a driver but you don't have chrome installed. `chromedriver` doesn't come with chrome itself.

I am not sure how would you resolve it but try installing chrome in [debug environment](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/debug-your-pipelines-locally-with-docker-838273569.html) and see it help you or not.

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to get it run using following bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
 image: versys650/angular-cli-for-e2e-tests

 pipelines:
   default:
    - step:
      script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
      - npm install    
      - ng test --singleRun=true
      - export DISPLAY=:1
      - Xvfb $DISPLAY -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x8 &
      - ng e2e --env=prod
```

Hope it will help somebody...